# Python module dependencies

Tags: python, dependencies

I'm trying to make my own module for easy sprite rendering & creation for personal uses. The only problem is, it needs pygame. If I were to put `import pygame` at the top of my module, could I then in another program, setup pygame instead of setting it up in the module? In general, does importing modules in one program, then importing that program into your main module, does the main program inherit the same dependencies, or do you need to explicitly re-import them?

Module to be used:

```
import pygame
def makeSprite():
    # todo write code INCLUDING PYGAME DEPENDENCIES
    pass
def updateSprite():
    # todo write code INCLUDING PYGAME DEPENDENCIES
    pass
```

Program using module:

```
import myModule  # myModule is the name of the module above
pygame.init()
makeSprite(arg1, arg2)
updateSprite(arg1, arg2)
pygame.functionCallFromPygame()
```

Can the main program also use the module? Thank you.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND Why? I've always been taught to put imports at the beginning of the file for consistency reasons.

Comment: @F3AR3DLEGEND At the start of each function? At the beginning, its makes it global, making it not needed to be imported over and over again...

Comment: If you import your module what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be a problem. As long as nothing tries to actually use pygame functionality before `pygame.init()` is called, it'll work fine.

(In other words, as long as whatever program using your library calls `pygame.init()` before calling your library's functions, you'll be fine.)